# using user input to setstate and then using the value of the state as part of the url for an axios request

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate

- everything was working before trying to have the first axios request use the state that was set by the user input.
- i think my problem might have something to due with the async nature of setState and axios

---

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      summonerLevel: "",
      accountId: "",
      matchHistory: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

### - the first axios request using this.state.name in the url

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var api_key = "...";
    axios
      .get(
        `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/${
          this.state.name
        }?api_key=${api_key}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        var { summonerLevel, accountId } = response.data;

        this.setState({ summonerLevel, accountId });
        console.log(this.state);
```

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so trying to use `this.state` directly after will not give you the updated state. You can try the second argument which is a callback that will be run when the state has been updated `this.setState({ summonerLevel, accountId }, () => console.log(this.state));`. Since you already have the variables that you set state with, there is no need to use `this.state` either.

Answer (score 1):

Your this.state.name is null at the beginning. so your request will be sent is 
https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/?api_key=...

try using

```
async componentDidMount() {
     var api_key = "...";
     await axios
      .get(
         `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/${
         this.state.name
         }?api_key=${api_key}`
      )
      .then(response => {
         const { summonerLevel, accountId } = response.data;
         this.setState({ summonerLevel, accountId });
         console.log(this.state);
         }
}
```